# Android: how to declare an activity as main and searchable?

Tags: android, searchable

I would like my main activity to be searchable also but when I change the manifest.xml to

```
 <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       <!-- declare the default searchable Activity for the whole app -->
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />            
 </intent-filter>
```

it cant find the main activity and the application doesn't run.
any idea?
is it not best practice to use the same activity as searchable also?
Thanks,
Alisa

Answer (score 19):

You need to add a new intent-filter with the action.SEARCH

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need add new action in manifest file and link to search metadata, smth like that:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

Comment: Take care with this solution: Your activity won't launch automatically. I did like you before, but Maragues answer saved me and give no issue