# android run works, debug not

Tags: android

Hello i am using an external library ( https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar )
with eclipse ( in eclipse->project->properties->android->library, also i unchecked "Is Library" ).

And now i can't debug, instead of getting a message of something like this

```
[2012-05-31 18:28:42 - MyLocationDemo] Uploading MyLocationDemo.apk onto device 'CM7-Blade'
[2012-05-31 18:28:42 - MyLocationDemo] Installing MyLocationDemo.apk...
[2012-05-31 18:28:44 - MyLocationDemo] Success!
```

I get this

```
[2012-05-31 18:27:28 - Reactivame] Uploading Abc.apk onto device 'CM7-Blade'
[2012-05-31 18:27:29 - Reactivame] Installing Abc.apk...
[2012-05-31 18:27:36 - Reactivame] Success!
[2012-05-31 18:27:36 - Reactivame] \Abc\bin\Abc.apk installed on device
[2012-05-31 18:27:36 - Reactivame] Done!
```

I tried using Log.v(), but not even that works. I restarted both the PC and the two testing devices i have, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with AndroidManifest.xml because i was trying to use my main activity as a searchable activity
here is the answer on how to do that [Android: how to declare an activity as main and searchable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739652/android-how-to-declare-an-activity-as-main-and-searchable)

Answer (score 2):

Log does not print to the console. Log prints to Logcat. In Eclipse do the following.

```
Window > Show View > Other > Android > Logcat
```

Alternately

```
Window > Show Perspective > Other > DDMS
```

Comment: Your post is confusing then, you posted output from the console. Not sure what relevance the console output has with Logcat output. Additionally are you sure your Logcat is reading output from the correct device. It can often crash due to buggy drivers and having multiple devices connected to a machine at one time can be problematic as well, at least in my experience.